# Is there a way to pause a code in the middle of a run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How do you handle a code where you have to pause the code at any given moment. For example, you could be reading files from server and server is going to be rebooted; you would want to pause the code so it stops trying to read the file from the server. You also wouldn't want to rerun the code if you have been running it for a long time. Is there a way to pause a code for certain amount of time in python?

I looked into this everywhere and couldn't find any solution.  There were few solution that was mentioned.

raw_input("") :if you are reading millions of file,I don't think you would want to manually enter every time it reaches this part of code.

sleep(): you wouldn't know when to pause the code and for how long so I don't think this would work.

There is a anything I can implement to take care of this issue?

Thanks,

Shone

I understand you don't see any snippet of code and I am sorry for not having any code snippet. I have been thinking about this issue and trying to find a solution in case this issue were to arise in future.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can put a while loop such that until you receive the required file from the server it wouldn't execute the rest of the code. Let me know if that was helpful?

Comment: If we were to use the while loop, it would continue to run even when the server is down?How efficient will that be? Is there now way to pause the code until you manually restart it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this will affect efficiency-wise but can't you use sleep() inside a while loop or something like that.
As in,

```
while not condition: sleep(100)
```

or just,

```
while not condition: pass
```

Comment: `while not condition: pass` is *terrible*, efficiency-wise. A simple condition could be evaluated millions of times per second, so unless you need microsecond response time, sleep for at least a little bit in the body.

Comment: If you were to use while loop, the code will continue to run until it reads a file right? Like chepner said, it will continue to execute the code. If you add a sleep, wouldn't the code sleep after reading each file causing it to be slow? Is there no pythonic way to halt the process?

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in the past is have my script periodically check for the existence of a `stop` file somewhere, which can be manually put there when you want to pause.

So for this contrived example of an infinite while loop, the script checks for the file, and if it exists, it goes into a sleep loop and continues to check every second. When the file disappears the main loop will continue

```
import time, os.path
while True: # Main processing loop
    while os.path.exists('path/to/file'):
        time.sleep(1)
    # Do processing stuff
    # here
```

It's a bit of an ugly hack, but simple to implement.